# Showing a latin 1 character in a UTF-8 page

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding

Here is a test.html file, saved with my text editor in latin 1 format:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
è
</body>
</html>
```

If a view the file in chrome, the è character is showed as a question mark. I don't understand why: è is part of latin 1 and latin 1 is supposed to be compatible with (a subset of) utf-8 so the code for the character è shouldn't be the same in latin 1 and utf-8?

If I change the charset to ISO-8859-1 of course everything is fine.

Thanks

Comment: [What every programmer must know about character encodings](http://kunststube.net/encoding)

Answer (score 9):

You are confusing the notion of character sets / codepages with encoding. UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) are encodings, they are a system of how to represent characters in bytes, not a list of characters that you choose from.

You save the file as ISO-8859-1, so your file has `0xE8`. You tell the browser that the file is encoded in UTF-8, so the browser tries to decode your file according to the rules of UTF-8. And `0xE8` is invalid in UTF-8.

When you tell the browser to decode it in ISO-8859-1, it works because `0xE8` is valid in ISO-8859-1 and a character is shown from the codepage of ISO-8859-1 according to the value of `0xE8`.

Also, ISO-8859-1 is a subset of *unicode* (the "codepages" of the utf encodings), not UTF-8. What that means is that the first 256 characters in the codepage of ISO-8859-1 are the same characters as the first 256 characters in unicode.

And there's more. Browsers actually never use ISO-8859-1 to decode your page, but secretly use Windows-1252 instead. This has been also specified in the [HTML-5 draft](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html#character-encodings-0)

Comment: I know the difference between charset and encoding, and yes, I know ISO-8859-1 is a subset of unicode (not utf-8) but still I don't understand: my assumption works with the first 128 characters so if instead of è I write e, everything works. I thought that not only the first 128 characters have the same code in latin1 and utf-8 but all the 256 characters...so is this the wrong part of my assumption?

Comment: @Eugenio the first 128 characters are encoded exactly the same in both ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8. In fact, they are encoded exactly the same in majority of encodings... Anyway, the other half of 128 characters are encoded differently in UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1, which makes ISO-8859-1 incompatible with UTF-8.

Comment: This means if there is an encoding problem, it isn't visible if only the 128 first characters are used. The 172th character in unicode is the same as 172th character in ISO-8859-1. But when *encoded* in UTF-8, the byte sequence is `0xC2, 0xAC`, where as when encoded in ISO-8859-1, the byte sequence is just `0xAC`. In ISO-8859-1 `0xC2, 0xAC` is `Â¬`, and in UTF-8 `0xAC is just invalid.

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense.
Reading something like "ISO-8859-1 was incorporated as the first 256 code points of ISO/IEC 10646 and Unicode" (what you can read on wikipedia for example) can be misleading.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Latin-1 characters in the range 128-255 are not valid within a UTF-8 context. Although they do share the same character codes, in UTF-8 they are represented differently. For instance, `è` in UTF-8 is actually `Ã¨`. `0xE8` is not a valid character in a UTF-8 string unless it is followed by two characters in the `\x80` to `\xBF` range, therefore you get the replacement character.

Comment: è in UTF-8 is not "actually Ã¨". è in UTF-8 is è. Compare bytes if you want to, not characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you save the file in Latin 1, then the charset attribute declaration that the encoding is UTF-8 is not true. 
You have to save the file in the encoding that the charset attribute declares.